# How can I identify which work items/user stories are in a selected build in Azure DevOps?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am new to Azure DevOps, so perhaps this is a really simple question. When selecting a build (there are many) to deploy to production, it would be great if I could identify the user stories or tasks were included in that build. I want to be able to say what work is being deployed before it is live, or tell customers who are waiting for new features when that feature is live.

I have tried to write a script using the [Azure DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and can see my builds and pull requests. But how do I link them? Is there an existing tool to do this maybe? It would also be great to say given a user story id (e.g. 171171), you could say which build it appears in. Is this possible or do this without saving all of the data from the API and reading this cached version?

Comment: Hi lemon, did any answer provide below solved your issue or helped?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have accepted @Sebastian's answer as it directly answers the title question. But the second part of my question remained unanswered, regarding the identification of the build in which a work item appears in, if you only have the work item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify work items (Bugs, User Storys, ...) when commiting to the Git-Repo. This is done by Hashtag and the work item number (e.g. #1234). Visual Studio also has a UI support for this, which does the same.

[image: Commit]

The linked work items will automatically be display at the Build summery page.
[image: Build]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say _"This is done by Hashtag and the work item number"_. Do you mean include the workitem number in the commit message and it will automatically be linked?

Also, is there an automatic way to get this information. So if I have a work item id I can find the build it was in?

Comment: For "Classic Builds" (not YAML Pipelines) there is an option when you edit your build definition under the "Options"-Tab --> "Automatically link new work in this build".
When enabled, builds will be linked to Work Items and appear in the "Development"-Section of the Work Item

Answer (score 0):

Just add work items into commit. Here is different options: [Linking Work Items to Git Branches, Commits, and Pull Requests](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/)