# in azure devops, How can we tell which stories are in a release candidate?

Tags: azure-devops, release-notes

We use continuous build and deploys up through a test environment, and each changeset is tied to a work item (story).  After the build is deployed to an environment, I *think* we can see every associated story for that build.  Question is what has changed, functionally, both for verification/acceptance tests and for release notes, support training, and marketing.  This is related to [How can I identify which work items/user stories are in a selected build in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450040/how-can-i-identify-which-work-items-user-stories-are-in-a-selected-build-in-azur) except that we want to know *before* the candidate moves to a higher level environment and to collect the sum of unique changes since this pipeline last promoted to that environment

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 2):

For this issue ,you could see related work items in Release stage page. It compares the current release with the previous release and then displays the newly added work items associated with changesets.

**Note**:If the current release deployed an older artifact, then the difference lists negative work items i.e., the changes that were rolled back from this stage.

[image]

In addition,you can also enable `Report deployment status to Work` for the stages under `Option` in the release pipeline, thus when the stage completes, it will create links to all work items linked to associated changes.

[image]

You can see if this is what you need.For the similar case,please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655380/is-it-possible-to-link-a-work-item-to-a-release) .